# Does pyenv uninstall remove all packages installed via pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, pyenv

I want to remove some older versions and I'm wondering do I have to remove all of the packages installed via pip first, then do a pyenv uninstall [version]?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In essence `pyenv uninstall` [removes](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/47436606b54b30d75feaff1bbcf029b84b7c6f4c/plugins/python-build/bin/pyenv-uninstall#L82) the entire directory with a python version. So yes, I'm sure it removes installed packages as they are in `$PREFIX/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help.